# java frameworks for web applications

Tags: playframework, oracle11g, web-deployment-project

I am new to Web App Development and am working on a small web application and have so far made all the HTML files which are linked to their respective CSS files. I have also used JavaScript for performing certain tasks such as the Validations etc. 
I now want to link my application to an Oracle Database, the schema for which is already made. 
Any suggestions regarding what framework (Java) I must use, for accomplishing database connectivity (Apart from Play 2.x)? And how the use of whichever will make my development process easier? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand you have everything for the browser (HTML, CSS, JavaScript) and what you need is the server side and you want to do it in Java. There are a couple frameworks that help you with that - the Play framework is only one possibility (although a very good choice for a small, easy-to-setup web application). Only to name some other: [Spark](http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html), [Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/home), [Ninja](http://www.ninjaframework.org/) and of course the quite heavy but still loved [Spring MVC](https://spring.io/).

For the connection to the database I'd recommend to use [Ebean](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaEbean) or [JPA](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaJPA). Both are similar, both are supported by Play, both work with a Oracle DB.

Probably best to start are example apps:

- One that uses Hibernate, an implementation of JPA: https://github.com/jamesward/play-java-jpa
- One that uses OpenJPA, another implementation of JPA: https://github.com/kristijanbambir/play-openjpa

And little tutorial about Play with JPA: http://www.waitingforcode.com/play-framework/database-and-jpa-in-play-framework/read.

Comment: Thanks! Helped a lot!